# How to count from 1 when remove a row ajax?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have to make a functionality that users can add and remove rows with input fields. Problem is that I need a row index (number) in front of each row incorrect order(1., 2., 3. etc.) also when one or more rows are removed and then added again. I can add rows but I can`t get the counting right because If I remove them then the count starts with 4 but I need 1 or if the second row gets removed then I need 2 instead of 4.

I have made it with append() and so far so good but I also need row cont in front of each row. I have a counter but let's say I add 1 row and it gives numbers 1 and 2. If I remove the second row and add another again, now the count is 1 and 3

Note that the "add" button is only one and separated from append();

I have three lines that are 1, 2, and 3, respectively

[image: three]

Now I will delete one of them. For example, I delete row number 2. I see this demo,

[image: 4,5]

This should not happen. It should show the numbers 1 and 2, respectively.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#educationalForm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($('#educationalForm')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{ route('educational.store') }}',
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data){
                    const variables = ['grade', 'major', 'end'];
                    variables.forEach(variable => {
                        if(data[variable] === null) data[variable] = '';
                    });
                    const newRowNum = $('#educationalForm tr').length + 2;
                    let html = '' +
                        '<tr>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal" id="demo">'+ (newRowNum) +'</td>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+data.grade+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+data.major+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+data.end+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+
                        '<form method="post" id="educational-destroy">'+
                        '@csrf'+
                        '@method('DELETE')'+
                        '<div class="btn-group">'+
                        '<a data-id="'+data.id+'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="educationalEdit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#educationalModal">ویرایش</a>'+
                        '<button data-id="'+data.id+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="educationalDestroy">حذف</button>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</form>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                    $('#educationalTable').append(html);
                    $('#educationalForm').trigger('reset');
                },
            });
        });

        showEducationals();

        function showEducationals() {
            $.get('{{ route('educational.index') }}', function (data) {
                $('#educationalTable').html("");
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    const variables = ['grade', 'major', 'end'];
                    variables.forEach(variable => {
                        if(val[variable] === null) val[variable] = '';
                    });
                    $('#educationalTable').append('<tr>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+ (key+1) +'</td>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+val.grade+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+val.major+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="fw-normal">'+val.end+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+
                        '<form method="post" id="educational-destroy">'+
                        '@csrf'+
                        '@method('DELETE')'+
                        '<div class="btn-group">'+
                        '<a data-id="'+val.id+'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="educationalEdit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#educationalModal">ویرایش</a>'+
                        '<button data-id="'+val.id+'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="educationalDestroy">حذف</button>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</form>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'
                    );
                });
            });
        }

        $(document).on('click', '#educationalEdit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'/educational/'+id+'/edit',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#id').val(data.educational.id);
                    $('#edit_grade').val(data.educational.grade);
                    $('#edit_major').val(data.educational.major);
                    $('#edit_avg').val(data.educational.avg);
                    $("input[name='edit_start']").val(data.educational.start);
                    $("input[name='edit_end']").val(data.educational.end);
                    $('#edit_docPlaceName').val(data.educational.docPlaceName);
                    $('#edit_thesisTitle').val(data.educational.thesisTitle);
                    $('#edit_docPlaceCountry').val(data.educational.docPlaceCountry);
                    $('#edit_docPlaceCity').val(data.educational.docPlaceCity);
                },
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#educationalUpdate', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $('#id').val();
            var file = $('#edit_upload_doc').prop('files')[0];
            var formData = new FormData($('#educationalFormUpdate')[0]);
            formData.append('file', file);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/educational/'+id,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#educationalModal').modal('hide');
                    showEducationals();
                },
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#educationalDestroy', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:'educational/'+$(this).data('id'),
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#educationalsTable').html('');
                    showEducationals();
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

So in general I can get counting right until elements are getting removed. If I got 3 rows I got a count of 1. 2. 3. but if I remove all of them and add again 3 rows I got 4. 5. 6. BUT I need 1. 2. 3. again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the counter every time you re-render the whole table.

You could move the `count` to inside your rendering function, but it is not strictly necessary, because [jQuery's `each` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback) already provides an index (you are naming it `key`) which you could use instead of `count`.

Therefore, you can do:

```
function showEducationals() {
    $.get('{{ route('educational.index') }}', function (data) {
        $('#educationalTable').html("");
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            const variables = ['grade', 'major', 'end'];
            variables.forEach(variable => {
                if(val[variable] === null) val[variable] = '';
            });
            $('#educationalTable').append('<tr>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">'+ (key+1) +'</td>'+ // using key instead of count
```

Notice I also removed `id=demo`. This is because you are creating several cells with the `id=demo` (in `'<td class="fw-normal" id="demo">'+count+++'</td>'+`) and ideally ids should be unique.

About adding new rows use, instead of `i`, the number of rows the table actually has:

```
$('#educationalForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($('#educationalForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:'{{ route('educational.store') }}',
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            const variables = ['grade', 'major', 'end'];
            variables.forEach(variable => {
                if(data[variable] === null) data[variable] = '';
            });
            const newRowNum = $('#educationalTable tr').length + 1; // added this
            let html = '' +
                '<tr>'+
                '<td class="fw-normal">'+ (newRowNum) +'</td>'+ // edited this
```

In addition, you should remove the `i` and `count` variables, as they are no longer necessary:

```
showEducationals();
let i;                 // remove this
let count = 1;         // remove this
function showEducationals() {
    // ...
            );
            i = count  // remove this
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a problem. When I delete rows. And I empty the table. But I will add another one starting from 2. I want to start with 1.

Comment: I have reworked the answer to handle that problem as well. Please check it out (you can reread it from the top).

Comment: I see this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).size is not a function`

Comment: Try `.length` instead if `.size()`

Comment: Also make sure you remove `i = count` if you remove the `i` and `count` variables.

Comment: I see added like 1, 2, ,2 ,2 ,2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237036/discussion-between-developer-laravel-and-acdcjunior).

Comment: where are you??

Comment: I have responded a while ago in the chat you created

Comment: Use `const newRowNum = $('#educationalTable tr').length + 1;` instead of `const newRowNum = $('#educationalForm tr').length + 2;`